# Hibernate - Many to Many with additional column - StackOverFlowException in refresh operation

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, vaadin, stack-overflow

I'm developing a solution with a relationship Many-To-Many (between User-Context) and an additional column (isAdmin) to kwon if the User is the administrator of the context.

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

but I get an error of StackOverFlowException when I do a Refresh of User container.

```
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIMsg.marshalTTCcode(T4CTTIMsg.java:223)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIrxd.marshal(T4CTTIrxd.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalBinds(T4C8Oall.java:1493)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshalAll(T4C8Oall.java:973)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal(T4C8Oall.java:422)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:796)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1031)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:836)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1124)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:722)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:722)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1090)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1038)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:630)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:438)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:722)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
```

My classes are:

Users.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users {
    private Long user_id;
    private Long niu;
    private String nom;
    private String mail;
    private Set<UserContext> userContexts  = new HashSet<UserContext>(0);

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade =
        {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true)
    public Set<UserContext> getUserContexts() {
        return userContexts;
    }
    public void setUserContexts(Set<UserContext> userContexts) {
        this.userContexts = userContexts;
    }

}
```

Context.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CONTEXT")
public class Context {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Area area;
    private String code;
    private Set<UserContext> userContexts = new HashSet<UserContext>(0);


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "pk.context", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Set<UserContext> getUserContexts() {
        return userContexts;
    }

}
```

UserContext.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_CONTEXT")
@AssociationOverrides({
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.context", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CTXT_ID")) })
public class UserContext implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserContextID pk = new UserContextID();
    private String admin;

    @EmbeddedId
    public UserContextID getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    @Transient
    public Users getUser() {
        return getPk().getUser();
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        getPk().setUser(user);
    }

    @Transient
    public Context getContext() {
        return getPk().getContext();
    }

    public void setContext(Context cntx) {
        getPk().setContext(cntx);
    }

    public void setPk(UserContextID pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }

    @Column(name = "ADMIN", unique = false, nullable = true, length = 1)
    public String getAdmin(){
        return admin;       
    }
    public void setAdmin(String admin) {
            this.admin = admin;
    }
}
```

UserContextID.java

```
@Embeddable
public class UserContextID implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9120607274421816301L;
    private Users user;
    private Context context;

    @ManyToOne
    public Users getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Users user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public void setContext(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Anybody have any idea about what could be happening? As I told you when I made a refresh() in User container the StackOverFlowException occurs. Help me, please!!